Meta Ads: App Conversion Ad set not publishing - Receiving events: Error Code 1815437
I am trying to run meta conversion ads for my app, but I cannot publish the campaign and receive the error code: 1815437
The error text is ( having been translated from German)

Missing or invalid field in the highlighted objects: application_id does not contain a valid entry for the optimisation target APP_INSTALLS. Please change the input in the highlighted objects. (#1815437)

Things I have checked:

Set up as business app - checked with others who run ads and this is OK
Ensured the app is LIVE
Checked that the SDK is up to date
Checked that I am receiving events




